# How to convert single arrays to double arrays

Tags: java

Here I made a code but with single array but now I want to convert it to double arrays [][].

There are some things should be changed but I can get it to work.

This is part of the class that got the a single array that I want to change to double arrays.

```
    public House[][] neighbors(House victim) {
    House[][] n = new House[8];

    int row = victim.address / size;
    int col = victim.address % size;

    if (row != 0 && row != (size - 1) && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address + size];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address + size - 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address + size + 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (row == 0 && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address + size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address + size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address + size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1))];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (row == (size - 1) && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (col == 0) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address + (size - 1)];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        return n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, by "double" array, you mean you want a 2D array. Since you did not specify what dimensions you want for the double array, I will assume `2 x 4` for this example.

Instead of writing

```
House[][] n = new House[8];
```

You want

```
House[][] n = new House[2][4];
```

Then, you want to replace every line of the following form:

```
 n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1]
```

with lines of the following form:

```
 n[0][1] = houses[victim.address - 1]
```

The first index specifes the row number, and the second index specifies the column number for your 2D array. You probably have a better idea than I do of which index pairs should match with which specific house.

Comment: For this part:  n[0][1] = houses[victim.address - 1]
i did it this way but it says: cannot convert from House[] to House.